# Options not diplaying in service menu (Samsung Galaxy Ace 2, Android 2.3.6)

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, microphone, samsung-galaxy-ace-2

I am struggling with very low in-call microphone volume (when I simply record sound it's fine). The common solution seems to require going to [5] AUDIO option in the service menu, but I can only see three items there: [1] DEBUG SCREEN, [2]VERSION INFORMATION and [3] COMMON. I'm using Samsung Galaxy Ace 2, running Android 2.3.6 (Gingerbread). I launch the service menu by dialing *#*#197328640#*#*.

Does anybody know a different way to get to the service menu AUDIO options or another way to boost in-call microphone volume?